# requireJS and AMD module/folder organisation

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

Can someone give me advice on organising files in RequireJs, I am looking for the best practice way of doing it that will allow the most flexibility in the future.

my current folder structure is as below. I come from a java background that is why I have called them classes (I am aware that they are objects not classes), I am willing to change this given a better suggestion.

```
scripts
    > startup.js
    > class
        > FromAddress.js
        > ToAddress.js
        > ...
    > common
        > class
            > Address.js
            > UrlResolver.js
            > ...
    > lib
        >jquery.js
        >jquery-ui-core.js
        > ...
    > page
        > home.js
        > sitemap.js
        > ...
```

`/scripts/startup.js` contains the requirejs configuration script and loads the appropriate `main` script from the `/scripts/page` folder

`/scripts/class` contains application specific classes

`/scripts/common/class` contains classes that could be shared with another projects (they will eventually reside in a separate project and be injected somehow)

`/scripts/lib` contains javascript 3rd party libraries

`/scripts/page` equivalent to `main.js` from the documentation, basically the startup script for each page in the application.

Comment: Do you have a problem with that file structure? Did anyone complain? Not clear what are you looking for...

Comment: @Alexei I am looking for best practice and most resistant to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found http://boilerplatejs.org/ which is really good.